# Multiple meanings of the C# 'event' keyword?

Tags: c#, events, keyword

I was recently re-reading some old posts on Eric Lippert's [ridiculously awesome](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) blog and came across [this tidbit](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/27/what-s-the-difference-between-fixed-and-fixed.aspx):

> A considerable fraction of the keywords of C# are used in two or more
>   ways: fixed, into, partial, out, in, new, delegate, where, using,
>   class, struct, true, false, base, this, event, return and void all
>   have at least two different meanings.

Just for fun my coworkers and I quizzed ourselves and I was able to come up with at least two uses for all but one of those keywords. The one that stumped me is `event`.

Obviously, using `event` when declaring a member field of a delegate type turns it into an event (e.g. only add/remove operators are exposed). What's the **other** meaning of event?

EDIT (Answer):

Thanks to @Hans Passant I dug up this bit out of the [C# spec](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=199552) that explains the other use of event -- as (the default) attribute target specifier for attributes on an event (from section 17.2):

> An attribute specified on an event declaration that omits event
>   accessors can apply to the event being declared, to the associated
>   field (if the event is not abstract), or to the associated add and
>   remove methods. In the absence of an *attribute-target-specifier*, the
>   attribute applies to the event. The presence of the `event`
>   *attribute-target-specifier* indicates that the attribute applies to the
>   event; the presence of the `field` *attribute-target-specifier* indicates
>   that the attribute applies to the field; and the presence of the
>   `method` *attribute-target-specifier* indicates that the attribute applies
>   to the methods.

Comment: Please link to the exact article, not the entire blog.

Comment: Any function which represents for a delegate is considered to be an event.For an example, Button Click is an Event. You can also have a custom event. Like User / Custome Controls have a custom event

Comment: @George: It's a question about a keyword in a programming language. Sounds on-topic to me. @Henk Holterman: Done.

Comment: "member field" - well, technically it isn't a field... it is an `event` ;p Does the subtlety between a field-like event (includes implementation) and an event (API signature only) count?

Comment: Err, sorry, wasn't paying attention to what URL got pasted into the question. My mistake, thanks for the edit :)

Comment: I'm sure once I see the answer I'm going to feel stupid, but how is void used in more than one way?

Comment: In unsafe code, void * is an "untyped" pointer, whereas the "void" keyword on a method means there *is no* return value.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. That is why I couldn't think of another way; I've never had a need to write unsafe code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the attribute target specifier.  I can't think of a good reason you would do this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Event)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute { }

class foo {
    [event: MyAttribute]
    public event EventHandler goo;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Would this ever be needed? I can understand `[assembly: ...]` but not his one.

Comment: Wow. I didn't know that was even an option. "Event" appears to be the only attribute target that is also a language keyword somewhere else, so I guess this is it.

Comment: The event target specifier appears to be the default if no specifier is given, so it's apparently never **needed**; I suppose you might want to use it for clarity if you have multiple attributes that target different parts of the event.

Comment: Yikes. A 100% redundant usage ;p Good memory digging that out (or were you clicking "next", "next", ... in the spec? ;p)

Comment: I wish I had the whole spec memorized! Once @Hans found the usage, I went to the attributes section of the spec and searched for event. It's only in that section a handful of times.

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to *use* `event` but I'm not sure if that qualifies.

```
public event MyDelegate MyEvent;

public event MyDelegate MyEvent
{
    add { ... }
    remove { ... }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was the distinction I was wondering about (see comments) - field-like events vs event API. Seems ... tenuous, though, IMO.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is correct. From the post: "Obviously we often use the same keyword to mean conceptually the same thing." I think `event` is one of those times.

Comment: @Marc: I think it's more of a "field-like notation". The actual result in both cases is an event with add&remove . Would an auto-property qualify as a different kind of property?

Comment: That's the closest I could come to a "second meaning" but it seemed like the keyword was being used in the same context for the same purpose: declare a class member of type event. I wouldn't consider "get;" and "get { return foo; }" two distinct uses of the "get" keyword...?

Comment: @Henk in the spec, they are explicitly called "field-like events". I was using it as per the terminology.

Comment: @Marc: agreed on the terminology but in this context I found it unclear. They are just 2 different notations, not 2 different things.

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), the two ways to use event are:

`[attributes] [modifiers] event type declarator;`

`[attributes] [modifiers] event type member-name {accessor-declarations};`

Comment: In every other case in the list of 'multiple-meaning' keywords, there were two distinct ways in which the keyword was used. Even if the meaning was closely related, the context was different -- using base.Method() to call a method vs using ": base()" to call a constructor. I was expecting there to be something more distinct about the "other" use of event than just the presence or absence of accessor declarations.